# googleVis (gvisTable) not rendering with shinydashboard app on R

Tags: r, browser, shiny, googlevis

I am currently building an application with shinydashboard and googleVis. gvisTable is in my opinion the best way to show my outputs. My problem is the following:

The application (and thus, googleVis) works perfectly with the R browser on my computer, but **if I want to show the application on an other computer**, the application starts and computes everything asked **but the tables are not rendering with gvisTable**. 
Since it works on my computer, I don't think the problem comes from the code, but I show you the used packages and an example of how I use gvisTable.

I use the following packages:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
library(texreg)
library(googleVis)
```

In the file server.R, when I want to output a table I use code like

```
output$coefftable <- renderGvis({
    ConfInv <- 0.05
    model <- Arima_Model()
    CoeffTable <- CoefficientsFunction(ConfInv,model)
    gvisTable(CoeffTable,options(digits=4))
  })
```

where the function CoefficientsFunction returns a table using data.frame.

For the output, I use in ui.R

```
htmlOutput("coefftable")
```

I don't understand where the problem comes from, it might be from the RStudio browser as suggested in [gvisTables not rendering in Shiny apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303156/gvistables-not-rendering-in-shiny-apps). 
Do you think I might use an other browser? If yes, which one would be the best?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your table and then return it inside server.R like this:

```
output$coefftable <- renderGvis({
ConfInv <- 0.05
model <- Arima_Model()
CoeffTable <- CoefficientsFunction(ConfInv,model)
table <- gvisTable(CoeffTable,options(digits=4))
return(table)
})
```